# Chrome url throttler extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There is an [extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/url-throttler/kpkeghonflnkockcnaegmphgdldfnden) for delaying requests. The problem is that it doesn't work with parallel requests. That is, if we set a mask for a domain, then we must wait until the files of images, styles, scripts, etc. are loaded one by one. There are 2 main files in the extension:

background.js

```
const delay = (ms) => {
  const startPoint = new Date().getTime()
  while (new Date().getTime() - startPoint <= ms) {/* wait */}
}

let handler;
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
  if (changes.hasOwnProperty('requestThrottler')) {
    const throttlerConfig = changes.requestThrottler.newValue;
    if (handler) {
      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(handler);
      handler = null;
    }

    const urls = throttlerConfig.urls.filter((u) => !u.error && u.url !== '').map((u) => u.url.trim());
    if (throttlerConfig.enabled && urls.length > 0) {
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icon48-warning.png'});
      handler = (info) => {
        console.log(`URL Throttler: Intercepted ${info.url}, going to wait ${throttlerConfig.delay} ms...`);
        delay(throttlerConfig.delay);
        console.log('URL Throttler: Done');
        return;
      };
      console.log('Blocking urls', urls);
      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        handler,
        // filters
        {
          urls: urls,
        },
        // extraInfoSpec
        ["blocking"]
      );
    } else {
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icon48.png'});
    }
  }
});
```

popup.js

```
const defaultURL = {
  url: '',
  error: false,
};
const urlRegex = /^(https?|\*):\/\/.*\/.*$/;

chrome.storage.local.get(['requestThrottler'], (result) => {
  const data = Object.assign(
    {}, {
      enabled: false,
      urls: [{ ...defaultURL }],
      delay: 5000,
    },
    result.requestThrottler
  );
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    methods: {
      addUrlInput: function() {
        this.urls = this.urls.concat({ ...defaultURL });
      },
      removeUrlInput: function(index) {
        this.urls.splice(index, 1);
      },
      updateStorage: _.debounce(function() {
        this.urls = this.urls.map((u) => {
          return {
            ...u,
            error: !urlRegex.test(u.url),
          };
        });
        chrome.storage.local.set({requestThrottler: {
          enabled: this.enabled,
          urls: this.urls,
          delay: this.delay,
        }});
      }, 700),
    },
    updated: function() {
      this.updateStorage();
    }
  });
});
```

My question is how to remake the script so that requests are processed in parallel?

ChatGPT cannot write an exact solution, although it gives seemingly working advice:

The problem is that the handler that is registered via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener is executed synchronously for each request.

This means that when parallel requests are received to two different URLs from the list, the handler blocks the execution of the first request for delay, then unblocks and blocks the second request also for delay.

In order for requests to be processed in parallel, you need to move the delay logic into a separate asynchronous function.

But for some reason he can’t write a working function...

Comment: Using a `while` loop to block the main thread (as this code does in the `delay` function) is mostly a bad idea. Not to mention that in manifest V3 the background script is actually a service worker. To be honest, it will be easier to just rewrite your code (I will have done that but I don't actually know what you're trying to do) then fix it.

Comment: The task is to emulate slow Internet. Since it is not possible to implement this in JavaScript in the browser, a solution was found to do it through an extension. But in this case, the extension processes requests one by one, and in parallel I will not be able to remake it.

Comment: In the Chrome browser's devTools, the **Network** tab has a throttling option (by default, is **No throttling**) that can be use to simulate different internet speeds. I'm sure the same functionality is available in other browsers.

Comment: I know about this possibility, I need a programmatic method.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to use the [`declarativeNetReques` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/declarativeNetRequest). This API can be used to manipulate HTTP(S) requests (I'm not sure if delaying them is a permitted way to manipulate them).

Comment: Extensions can emulate most features of devtools by using `chrome.debugger` API to send a CDP command. Network throttling is enabled via [Network.emulateNetworkConditions](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions).